# How can I pass a function to parent component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, web, react-hooks

In my React project, I want to keep all my functions in a single file and then I want to use the functions where I need. I can pass via props but that way I can't pass the function to parent components. Some people suggesting me to use context API. I can pass static data through context API but I don't know how can I pass the function. Can any one of you give me a possible solution or idea for this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just export and import the function here? Doesn't sound like there's any state that the dependent on,

Comment: You can include the file where needed and import the functions. Module files are only executed once, and the exports are used from there on.

Comment: Why not import your functions from that file where you need them? Don't use `context` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a `utils.js` file as below

```
export function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

You can then import that function in a component like so

```
import { add } from './utils';

const result = add(2, 3);

function App() {
  return <div>{result}</div>
};
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks, man! You explained so nicely.